# increase Service Worker life time

Tags: javascript, push-notification, addeventlistener, server-sent-events, service-worker

I'm trying push notifications using service workers.
use my own server to send notifications and eventSource is used to establish the connection. 
after i open the webpage service worker is running perfectly. but it stops after few seconds.
what i want is to run service worker without getting stopped. i want it to run until the browser is opened. can anyone recommend a way to do that. ?

this is my ServiceWorker JS

```
/**
 * 
 */
'use strict';
var eventSource2 = new EventSource("Servlet");
console.log('Started', eventSource2);
eventSource2.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    eventSource2.skipWaiting();
    console.log('Installed', event);

});

eventSource2.addEventListener('push',function(event) {
                    console.log(event.data);
                    var title = event.data;
                    self.registration.showNotification(title,{
                                        'body' : event.data,
                                        'icon' : 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-multimedia/1024/iMac-icon.png',
                                        'tag' : 'click',
                                    });
                    console.log("data from down", event.data);
                });

eventSource2.addEventListener('activate', function(event){
    console.log('Activated', event);
});

eventSource2.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log('Push message', event);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Service workers are meant to have a short lifetime, you can't make them run forever.

You could use a shared worker to do that, but they only run if your website is open.

You are trying to mix the push API and EventSource. If you use the Push API, you don't need to keep the service worker alive all the time, you can just make it execute when a push notification arrives.

See the [example on the ServiceWorker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/push-simple.html).

Comment: but i want it to run anytime when notification pops. like facebook.any suggestion ?

Comment: Why do you need to run it all the time? You only need to execute the service worker when a push notification arrives!

Comment: but it doesn't work like that. i don't know why. I'm using server sent events. 
After Service Worker went idle. i won't listen to push event. there for all the messages which are passing during Service Worker idle. won't receive to the client. Client have to load the page in order to reactive the Service worker.
i can't use GCM (due to organisational policy)

Comment: If you can't use the Push API (with Mozilla's push service or GCM), then there's no way to do what you want. EventSource doesn't work when your tab is closed.
If you are building a system that is only used internally by your company and you don't want to use a third-party service, you could build your own push service.

Comment: Thanks. it is a helpful answer. Can you recommend any useful resource to build a push service. ?

Comment: Mozilla's push service is opensource (https://github.com/mozilla-services/autopush), I think you can just download it and run it on your server. Then you will need to modify the browsers' settings to use your service instead of the default one (this is why it's feasible only if your system is going to be used only by your company, since you have to change the browsers' settings).

Comment: Thanks. yes. my system is for internal use only.therefore I think this might help. thanks again. I'll try that.

Comment: I have another question. what if i don't have HTTPS. ? does service worker support only https ?

Comment: Thanks...that was helpful

Comment: is there anyway to develop this in a http instead of https ?

Comment: In Firefox you can enable Service Workers over HTTP when the developer tools are open from the developer tools options (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Dev_tools). I guess there's a similar option in Chrome. You can't do it in production though, only while developing.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch a push like here:

`self.addEventListener('push',function(event) {`

the first thing to do is to use `event.waitUntil()` who takes a promise and extends the lifetime of the event and the serviceworker

```
self.addEventListener('push',function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(<YOUR PROMISE>)
}
```

Comment: Virtual beer for you my friend.  Cheers for that trick

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and it's not the purpose of a service-worker. Why exactly do you want to keep it alive ?

Comment: when ever a notification comes up from the server i want it to be displayed immediately. but after the service worker stopped running it won't pass any message to the client (push notification). that's why i want it to run all the time

Comment: In fact the service-worker registered is not really stopped but just idle. It's waiting for event such as push to wake up. So no need to keep it "alive".

Some good exemples of push notification with service-worker are available here : [https://serviceworke.rs/](https://serviceworke.rs/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Server sent event to send notifications. After Service worker went idle it won't listen to the push event. Therefor client going to miss some notifications while service worker is idle.